# How to redirect a request from http to https using nginx

Tags: nginx

How to redirect a request from http://example.com:8080 to https://example.com:8080 using nginx?

I'm working on this project https://github.com/JKHeadley/appy.git for which I use nginx to direct requests from port 80 to port 443. Nginx redirects to the location of the frontend web-app on port 3000.

The webapp redirect backend-api on port 8080.

Now on the front-end web-app when I click on one of the social media links, for example Facebook. The request is going to Facebook with my Facebook creds from the Appy server. But when the request is redirected back to the Appy server the request is coming on:

http://example.com:8080/auth/face-book&state=ZXn29Y7PsAX17Fso7cfHQ1&scope=email

Facebook throws the following error:

`Facebook has detected that Appy-World isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.`

So I would like to redirect the request coming back from outside server on http://example.com:8080/auth/facebook to https://example.com:8080/auth/facebook, so that a secure connection can be established successfully.

To check above scenario u can visit this url http://myappy.cf

below is my config file.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



server {

listen 443 ssl;
server_name _;
# server_name myappy.cf;



ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
ssl_buffer_size 8k;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;


ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# OCSP stapling
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;




access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;

location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://web:3000;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  proxy_redirect      http://web:3000 https://web:3000;
}
```

}

Is the above scenario possible and can we resolve this problem with nginx?
If yes, how can I resolve/achieve it?, what exactly i need to add in this config file to achieve my goal.
If no, what could be the alternative solution?

Quick response will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Redirecting won't solve the problem. You need to fix your application so that it generates correct URLs, i.e. with the https scheme, and not port 8080.

Comment: The problem is still within your web application. Since it seems to be an almost entirely undocumented sample app, you may want to have a chat with its maintainers about what needs to be done. Consider opening an issue on their github.

Comment: i will do that and check with them,thanks Micheal Hampton

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Nginx http to https redirect. The following site explains the redirect in detail: https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx.

I assume your problem should be fixed by adding this code to your nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Facebook normally redirects to the url where the request came from, so if you send the request from https it should be redirected to https. With the above code you catch-all port 80 (http) requests and redirect them to port 443 (https). So the complete site should serve https.

You should also check if the Valid OAuth Redirect URI is https in your Facebook settings under:
Facebook Login > Settings.

There is also an option to disable 'Enforce HTTPS' but disabling this option is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be it:

```
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot #you said you host it on 443 and 80, so here we are on https (that one is for ipv6)
        listen 443 ssl; # that one is for ipv4
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; #i suggest using letsencrypt certs as they're free
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; #same as above
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # i'm using 4096 bit rsa because it's safer and gives better results on ssllabs.com
        server_name example.com; #your server name
        access_log /var/log/example.access; #logs are good to know if someone messes up
        error_log /var/log/example.error;
        location / { #now the real magic
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; #you should give an address with port you use to access the application locally
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
server { #that clause is for redirecting http connections to https
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

If that doesn't work - comment my message and we'll try to find out why do you get redirects to port 8080 if you host the app on port 3000.

EDIT: I saw your project README and personally I'd try doing the same for the backend with usage of the domain api.example.com with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;`.